# Modifying gnome-shell.css

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, css

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and I am trying to personalize the Gnome Shell theme by modifying /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css but have been finding it very slow going.  There does not appear to be any documentation so I have had to resort to trial and error (lots of trial, lots of errors) and to studying other themes---e.g., Arc, Axiom, Human-NEXT and Maxim---to get the effects I want.

However, I still can't figure out many things. What is a .candidate-popup-boxpointer as opposed to a .popup-menu-boxpointer?  Where is it used?  Is it possible to have different values for .popup-menu-boxpointer for different uses--e.g., the notifications area as opposed to the dash's context menus?  What other parts of CSS do not work in addition to not being able to define named colors using

```
@define-color <name> <value>;
```

and not being able to use nth-child in addition to first-child and last-child?

Has any one found any documentation or at least commented examples?  www.gnome.org has lots of general info, but no specifics for theming the shell as opposed to gtk+ applications that I could find.

Comment: The CSS is generated from SASS, so https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell-sass maybe useful (it seems to have more comments, anyway)

Comment: It seems gnome's CSS differ from ordinary css, `nth-child` is not working, there is `-natural-hpadding` instead of `padding`, and ...